# Kill a spawned process in a Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am spawning a process using JavaScript.

```
spawn('Notepad.exe');
```

How do I kill it at certain event ?

Comment: Who is executing this javascript, and what javascript library are you using? "spawn" is not part of the standard javascript functions, nor is it possible in a typical javascript runtime to execute arbitrary programs.

Comment: This is part of a mozilla firefox plugin.

Comment: Firefox add-ons use `nsIFile.launch()` or `nsIProcess.run()` to create a process. What is "spawn"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a process using [nsIProcess.runAsync()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess#runAsync%28%29) or `nsIProcess.runw()` (the usual way for a Firefox add-on) then you can use `nsIProcess.kill()` to kill that process.

```js
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
              .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(notepadFile);
process.runAsync([], 0);
...
process.kill();
```